# Как сделать 3 WebKitView динамичного размера на 1 ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

Мне нужно вывести в `ViewController` новость, таким вот образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все данные берутся из апи, в виде html кода.
Вывести данные в `WebKitView` у меня получается, но вот как правильно расставить констрейнты чтобы страница была динамичной и скролились не webview, а весь контроллер.
Вставил все это дело в `ScrollView`, отключил скроллинг у `webview` и все равно стоит мертвым грузом.
`ScrollView` настроен правильно, в этом я уверен
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270287/wkwebview-inside-scroll-view

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ очень помог